# Handle string bundle in JUnit Test case

Tags: string, junit, bundle

How can I handle the String bundles, real one or faked?

1. I have a lots of cases affect each other of the String bundle, some legal codes write as below:

   ```
   //example

   private static I18n myInstance = I18n.getInstance().get(Example.class);
   ```

If all the cases run together, then this string bundle value will never reload because of it is static, actually different products have different string bundle values, then cause some case failed.

2. If not use the real string, the codes cannot run, because of the codes logic is base on the string bundle, seems only way is use real string bundle or fake the real value.

   ```
   //example

   if(isValue(myRB.getString("key")))
   {
      .....
   }
   ```

Comment: Because legal codes, if we change all static I18n to no static, cannot easy to use mock I18n inject to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the `I18n` instance into your class under test and mock `I18n` in the test.

```
public class YourClass {
  private final I18n i18n;

  public YourClass(I18n i18n) {
    this.i18n = i18n;
  }
}
```